# How to add a mask to a panel before the store loads and remove after the store loads

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I need to add a Loading Mask to my Tab Panel in sencha, I have a store being loaded via an Ajax Request in my Controller, But before the store loads I need to Put a loading mask, and After the store has been loaded I need to remove it.
This is my code so far

My Controller

```
Ext.define('QvidiApp.controller.MyController', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

config: {
},

beforeLoad: function() {
    Ext.Ajax.on('beforeLoad', function (con, opt) {
            Ext.getCmp('mainTabPanel').setMasked({
                       xtype: 'loadmask',
                       message: 'Loading...',
                       indicator:true
            });
    }, this);
},

getGender: function() {
    Ext.Ajax.request({

        method: 'POST',
        timeout: 25000,
        disableCaching : true,
        useDefaultHeader : true,
        params: {
            class: 'Qvidi',
            method: 'getDataM'
        },
        url: 'server/index.php',
        success: function( response ){
            var r = Ext.decode( response.responseText );
            Ext.getStore('GenderStore').setData( r.results );
        }
    });

    Ext.getCmp('mainTabPanel').setMasked(false);

},

afterLoad: function() {
        Ext.getCmp('mainTabPanel').setMasked(false);
},

init: function(application) {
    QvidiApp.app.getController('MyController').beforeLoad();
    QvidiApp.app.getController('MyController').getGender();
    QvidiApp.app.getController('MyController').afterLoad();
    console.log('loaded');
}

});
```

And Here is my Tab Panel Code

```
{
            xtype: 'tabpanel',
            id: 'mainTabPanel',
            ui: 'light',
            layout: {
                type: 'card',
                animation: 'scroll'
            },
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    title: 'Welcome',
                    iconCls: 'home',
                    id: 'welcomeTab',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'image',
                            centered: true,
                            height: 85,
                            width: 318,
                            src: 'http://104.155.111.158/qvidim/PowerdbyNfinity.png'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    title: 'Data',
                    iconCls: 'organize',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'dataview',
                            height: 465,
                            id: 'dataview',
                            masked: true,
                            itemTpl: [
                                '    <tpl>',
                                '        <table style="width: 100%;">',
                                '            <tr>',
                                '                <td><div style="width:5em; text-align: left">{gender}</div></td>',
                                '                <td><div style="width:5em; text-align: left">{glances} </div></td>',
                                '                <td><div style="width:5em; text-overflow: ellipsis; display: block; overflow: hidden; text-align: left">{title}</div></td>',
                                '            </tr>  ',
                                '        </table>',
                                '        <hr>',
                                '    </tpl>'
                            ],
                            store: 'QvidiDataStore'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    title: 'PieChart',
                    iconCls: 'info',
                    layout: 'fit',
                    scrollable: 'vertical',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'polar',
                            id: 'genderPieChart',
                            colors: [
                                '#115fa6',
                                '#94ae0a',
                                '#a61120',
                                '#ff8809',
                                '#ffd13e',
                                '#a61187',
                                '#24ad9a',
                                '#7c7474',
                                '#a66111'
                            ],
                            store: 'GenderStore',
                            series: [
                                {
                                    type: 'pie',
                                    labelField: 'types',
                                    xField: 'counter'
                                }
                            ],
                            interactions: [
                                {
                                    type: 'rotate'
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    title: 'BarChart',
                    iconCls: 'info',
                    scrollable: 'vertical',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'chart',
                            centered: true,
                            height: 374,
                            colors: [
                                '#24ad9a',
                                '#7c7474',
                                '#a66111'
                            ],
                            store: 'ClipsViewed',
                            axes: [
                                {
                                    type: 'category',
                                    fields: [
                                        'title'
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    type: 'numeric',
                                    fields: [
                                        'viewed'
                                    ],
                                    grid: {
                                        odd: {
                                            fill: '#e8e8e8'
                                        }
                                    },
                                    position: 'left'
                                }
                            ],
                            series: [
                                {
                                    type: 'bar',
                                    style: {
                                        minGapWidth: 1,
                                        minBarWidth: 80,
                                        maxBarWidth: 80
                                    },
                                    xField: 'title',
                                    yField: [
                                        'viewed',
                                        'glances'
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            interactions: [
                                {
                                    type: 'panzoom'
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    title: 'ClipsGenderChart',
                    iconCls: 'info',
                    scrollable: 'vertical',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'chart',
                            centered: true,
                            height: 378,
                            colors: [
                                '#ff8809',
                                '#7c7474'
                            ],
                            store: 'ClipsGenderStore',
                            axes: [
                                {
                                    type: 'category',
                                    fields: [
                                        'title'
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    type: 'numeric',
                                    fields: [
                                        'male'
                                    ],
                                    grid: {
                                        odd: {
                                            fill: '#e8e8e8'
                                        }
                                    },
                                    position: 'left'
                                }
                            ],
                            series: [
                                {
                                    type: 'bar',
                                    style: {
                                        minGapWidth: 1,
                                        minBarWidth: 80,
                                        maxBarWidth: 80
                                    },
                                    xField: 'title',
                                    yField: [
                                        'male',
                                        'female'
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            interactions: [
                                {
                                    type: 'panzoom'
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            tabBar: {
                docked: 'bottom',
                ui: 'light'
            }
        }
```

I do not know why this does not work, i tested it in Chrome developer console, and this is the error I get on the console

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setMasked' of undefined

Comment: have you tried to add # before the id 
I mean    `Ext.getCmp('#mainTabPanel')`

Comment: and it's more recommended if you use itemId instead of Id 
to keep the auto generated id for components

Comment: No, there's no change

Comment: does it give you the same erro

Comment: So must I change the id to ItemId and use a # for the getCmp

Comment: yes try it and you can try  `Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#itemId")[0]`
instead of  `Ext.GetCmp()`

Comment: The code doesn't really make sense. I don't see why you're calling all those things synchronously, if you wanted any masking to take place you would need to do the mask before making the request, then clear it after the request completes. In this case you clear the mask as soon as you fire off the request. Also, there's no `beforeload` event on `Ext.Ajax`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use beforeload and load event listeners to set and reset the mask like in below example

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
    autoLoad: false,
    fields: ['id', 'name'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'items'
        }
    },
    listeners: {
        beforeload: function(store, eOpts) {
            // You may want to get panel reference dynamically
            panel.mask("loading...");
        },
        load: function(store, eOpts) {
            // You may want to get panel reference dynamically
            panel.unmask();
        }
    }
});

var panel = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: store,
    columns: [{
        text: 'Id',
        dataIndex: 'id',
        flex: 1
    }, {
        text: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        flex: 1
    }],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});

Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
    text: 'Load Data',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    handler: function() {
        store.load();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not really make sense. this example must work. If you anything is unclear ask in comment

Controller

```
Ext.define('QvidiApp.controller.MyController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    init: function(application) {
        this.control({
            "#genderPieChart": {
                afterrender: this.loadPieChartStore
            }
        });
    }

    loadPieChartStore: function(component) {
        var tabPanel = component.up("tabPanel[id=mainTabPanel]");
        tabPanel.setMasked({
                   xtype: 'loadmask',
                   message: 'Loading...',
                   indicator:true
        });
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            method: 'POST',
            timeout: 25000,
            disableCaching : true,
            useDefaultHeader : true,
            params: {
                class: 'Qvidi',
                method: 'getDataM'
            },
            url: 'server/index.php',
            success: function( response ){
                var r = Ext.decode( response.responseText );
                Ext.getStore('GenderStore').setData( r.results );
                tabPanel.setMasked(false);
                console.log('loaded');
            },
            failure:function(){
                tabPanel.setMasked(false);
            }
        });
    },

});
```

View

```
{
    xtype: 'container',
    title: 'PieChart',
    iconCls: 'info',
    layout: 'fit',
    scrollable: 'vertical',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'polar',
            itemId: 'genderPieChart',
            colors: [
                '#115fa6',
                '#94ae0a',
                '#a61120',
                '#ff8809',
                '#ffd13e',
                '#a61187',
                '#24ad9a',
                '#7c7474',
                '#a66111'
            ],
            store: 'GenderStore',
            series: [
                {
                    type: 'pie',
                    labelField: 'types',
                    xField: 'counter'
                }
            ],
            interactions: [
                {
                    type: 'rotate'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```